# Reading error from Apple enhanced push notification with PHP

Tags: php, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Im trying to trigger an error so I can build in error logging for APNS. Therefore Im sending a too large payload to the server. But I get no error.

**Code:**

Connecting:

```
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $this->_sslPem);
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', "");

$this->_apnsConnection = stream_socket_client("ssl://" . Config::$apns['host'] . ":" . Config::$apns['port'], $error, $errorString, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

if ($this->_apnsConnection) {
    stream_set_blocking($this->_apnsConnection, 0);
}
```

Sending notification:

```
$this->_log("Sending notification to device token '$deviceToken'");

$identifiers = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $identifiers[$i] = rand(1, 100);
}

$apnsMessage = chr(1) . chr($identifiers[0]) . chr($identifiers[1]) . chr($identifiers[2]) . chr($identifiers[3]) . pack('N', time() + 3600) 
    . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($message)) . $message;
$bytes = fwrite($this->_apnsConnection, $apnsMessage);

$this->_log("bytes written: $bytes");

$this->_log("Fetching response");
$response = fread($this->_apnsConnection, 6);

$this->_log("Strlen: " . strlen($response));

if ($response === false || strlen($response) != 6) {

    $this->_log("No response...");
} else {

    $responseArray = unpack('Ccommand/CstatusCode/Nidentifier', $response);
    $this->_log("Response!");
    $this->_log($responseArray);
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-07-12 16:25:55: Sending notification to device token 'XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX'
2011-07-12 16:25:55: bytes written: 438
2011-07-12 16:25:55: Fetching response
2011-07-12 16:25:55: Strlen: 0
2011-07-12 16:25:55: No response...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a solution for this.

**Solution:**

```
$read = array($this->_apnsConnection);
$null = null;
$changedStreams = stream_select($read, $null, $null, 0, 1000000);

if ($changedStreams === false) {    

    $this->_log("Error: Unabled to wait for a stream availability");
} elseif ($changedStreams > 0) {

    $responseBinary = fread($this->_apnsConnection, 6);
    if ($responseBinary !== false || strlen($responseBinary) == 6) {

        $response = unpack('Ccommand/Cstatus_code/Nidentifier', $responseBinary);
        $this->_log($response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because of stream_set_blocking($this->_apnsConnection, 0); fread will return immediately before the error has a chance to be sent, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034926/iphone-push-notification-error-response-problem