# Push notification is coming in one device, but not in another device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Push notification is coming on my iPhone and iPad, but it is not coming on another iPhone when I send it. I can't understand why it's not  coming. 
I have created all the required certificates. add device ids. Still its not coming.Please help.(It's in sandbox mode).

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to send notification using  https://pushtry.com

ERROR Response Command: 8   Identifier: 0   Status: 8-Invalid token

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some Devices Not Receiving Apple Push Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681377/some-devices-not-receiving-apple-push-notifications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

1. Check if the same provisioning profile is being used while installing app in all your device
2. if its same.. go to developer.apple.com to see if the all your devices are checked in, for the provisioning profile you are using
3. Now in debug mode, check if

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
   var deviceTokenStr = deviceToken.description.replacingOccurrences(of: ">", with: "", options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil)
   deviceTokenStr = deviceTokenStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "<", with: "", options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil)
   deviceTokenStr = deviceTokenStr.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "", options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil)
   print(deviceTokenStr)
   }
   ```

this method is geting called, i.e all your devices are geting registered for push notification service

now, inside the above method, get your push notification token  "deviceToeknStr" and use it to check the push notification using site

https://pushtry.com

using your pem file, passphrase for the certificate and the devicetokenStr, in debug mode.