# Update passes of passbook

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, passbook

How to update passes of passbook by push notification. I get the pushtoken by webservice url. but i don't know how to update passes through push notification.

i am using simple php file for push notification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a push notification for a pass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877496/how-to-make-a-push-notification-for-a-pass).  Everything you need is in the [Wallet Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195).  You need to send a Push Request authenticated by your Pass Type ID certificate to the Apple APNS Production server.

Comment: how to get device id, if app is not installed in that device

Comment: Device ID is given to you in the URL of the webService when it returns the Device Token.

Comment: But the Device ID is not required to initiate the push - only the Device Token is required.

Comment: how to send push notification, there is any php or java file for sending push notification for passbook

Comment: Is Google down, or are you in China?

Comment: i am search but not find it the passbook push notification code through push token

Comment: There are dozens : https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=google+php+apns&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: every apns service required device token, but i have only push token

Comment: You are mistaken - you only need push token.

Answer (score 0):

check this, I use this code to send push notification to iOS, but I still finding for android

[PHP Apple Enhanced Push Notification read error response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058768/php-apple-enhanced-push-notification-read-error-response)