# how to add passes that get dynamic info from my app to wallet from in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, passbook, wallet

I created the my own .pkpass file with dummy data

I need to change the data in the pass according to the data in the app

like boarding pass

if I missed something , could please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will require a new .pkpass bundle for every change to the pass.

A new bundle will need to be signed. For security reasons, this should not take place on the device as it risks compromising your Pass Type ID certificate.

When you want to change the data, you should request a new pass bundle from your server and use the PassKit APIs to replace the pass in the Wallet.

Comment: yes. I got Thank you.. Now the server is generating the .pkpass file ..but how to get it in the app ?..  I need swift code to take pkpass file from the server ... Thank you again I really appreciate it

Comment: @Passkit Could you help me on this question please ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849883/cant-push-notification-to-apns-to-update-my-pass-in-apple-wallet?noredirect=1#comment66998009_39849883

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement full loop system according to Apple Passbook/wallet standard or at least you have to like this.

1. in pkpass file add webService, serialNumber (text and number), authenticationToken (text and number at least 16 characters), passTypeIdentifier and teamIdentifier value (register and download certification file from apple developer account). It has to be https and point to your server.
2. create push notification system to devices that keep your passes by using certification file (cer) and create p12 and pem files (you can find how to make it here: [Update Passbook wallet failed to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784620/update-passbook-wallet-failed-to-connect/34798838?s=1|0.4621#34798838))
3. create update web service to manage request from device and return new pkpass file to devices

others that: you have to make web service to manage register, update and delete method from devices.

Comment: Actually - through an app, you do not need to push, nor provide the web service.  Your app, if provisioned correctly has the authority to add, replace and delete wallet content through the PassKit APIs.  Open an NSURLConnection to your server (using whatever protocol and authentication you choose), retrieve an updated .pkpass bundle, then through your app code, replace the pass on in the Wallet.