# fread() issue with Stream Context

Tags: php, fread

My application sends iOS notification. I use `fread()` to check if there was an error in the response from the Apple server. However, the code gets stuck in a loop or just keeps on loading.

```
$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apnsCert = 'j_.pem';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsPass = '';
$notification = "hey";

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $apnsPass);
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://'.$apnsHost.':'.$apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);


$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $notification, 'sound' => 'default','link'=>'https://google.com','content-available'=>"1");
$output = json_encode($payload);
$token = pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', "device_token"));
$apnsMessage = chr(0).chr(0).chr(32).$token.chr(0).chr(strlen($output)).$output;
fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);    
$response = fread($apns,6);
fclose($apns);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: My question , why the process doesn't get complete. It keeps processing .

Comment: I would throw in some debug lines to figure out how far it gets and where it stops/get stuck. When I use a PHP script that does not display on screen, I will send myself emails instead from different points in the script and then I can figure out more specifically what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely blocking on`$response = fread($apns,6);` as is explained in similar questions, on success no bytes are returned to be read so it'll sit there forever waiting for 6 bytes to read.

It's better to do like ApnsPHP has done in the past, and use `select_stream()` to determine if there is anything to read, *before* trying to read it. Try replacing `$response = fread($apns,6);` with:

```
$read = array($apns);
$null = NULL;
//wait a quarter second to see if $apns has something to read
$nChangedStreams = @stream_select($read, $null, $null, 0, 250000);
if ($nChangedStreams === false) {
    //ERROR: Unable to wait for a stream availability.
} else if ($nChangedStreams > 0) {
    //there is something to read, time to call fread
    $response = fread($apns,6);
    $response = unpack('Ccommand/Cstatus_code/Nidentifier', $response);
    //do something with $response like:
    if ($response['status_code'] == '8') { //8-Invalid token 
        //delete token
    }
}
```